# Not Getting Latest date's using date parameter

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is my query.

```
AND PTP.END_DATE  = (Select MAX(END_DATE) FROM PAY_TIME_PERIODS WHERE END_DATE <=:to_date)-- Parameter
```

I'm trying to get latest end date from table but not getting all persons latest dates getting only few persons only.

If you have any Idea please help me

Comment: That cannot be your query. There are no valid queries that begin with the word `AND`. Show the full query, and describe the table(s) from which the data is queried, and the desired result. You explained most of the desired result; in that regard: if there are two rows with the same, latest date, for a given person, which should be preferred? (or return ALL those rows?)

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to write the query, but you don't provide much information.

Your subquery would seem to need a correlation clause:

```
PTP.END_DATE = (SELECT MAX(END_DATE)
                FROM PAY_TIME_PERIODS PTP2
                WHERE PTP2.?? = PTP.?? AND END_DATE <=:to_date
               )-- Parameter
```

The `??` is for whatever column identifies a person in your table.

Comment: what should i give in ?

Comment: @Babu - a unique column from your tabe. That part of the subquery is to correlate it with the main query. Basically you're saying *which* maximum date you want to find for each row.